# `npm list --global` doesn't show any packages

Tags: npm

I would expect `npm list --global` to tell me about the packages in `$(npm -g root)`:

```
$ npm -g root
/home/ravi/.local/share/npm/lib/node_modules
$ ls $(npm -g root) | head -n3
abbrev
acorn
acorn-dynamic-import
```

But instead it is looking elsewhere:

```
$ npm list --global
/home/ravi/.local/share/npm/lib
└── (empty)
```

Here is my configuration:

```
$ npm config get | grep -v -e '^;' -e '^$'
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/5.3.0 node/v8.5.0 linux x64"
userconfig = "/home/ravi/.config/npm/npmrc"
cache = "/home/ravi/.cache/npm"
init-module = "/home/ravi/.config/npm/config/npm-init.js"
link = true
prefix = "/home/ravi/.local/share/npm"
tmp = "/run/user/1000/npm"
```

How do I use `npm -g list` and get meaningful output?